# No sound on certain mp4 videos (audio codec: MPEG-4 AAC) in Windows 10 that work in Android (with earphones only) & Linux

Tags: windows, video, mp4, aac, mpeg

Update: in Android there is only sound on these videos when I have earphones plugged in. No sound will play on my phone's speakers.

The audio works on a set of mp4 videos when I play them in Ubuntu and in Android but not when I play them on any media players in Windows 10 on my laptop, including VLC. The properties of these videos:

Audio
Codec: MPEG-4 AAC
 
Channels: Stereo
Sample rate: 44100 Hz
 
Bitrate: 128 kbps

Video
Codec: H.264 (High Profile)
Framerate: 24 frames per second
Bitrate: 695 kbps

I am able to play other mp4 videos with the same codecs in Windows 10 without any problems. How can I fix the audio on these videos?

Comment: Do you have k lite codec installed?

Comment: @TamalesRancheros Yes I installed k lite codec and still have the same problem. There is something about the audio on this particular set of mp4 files. Hoping I can find out how to fix it and what is it about Ubuntu Linux that makes it work and why on Android I only have audio with the earphones plugged in for just this set of mp4 files while the audio is fine on other mp4 files.

Answer (score 0):

A suggestion from YouTube seems to explain the reason.

If your video's sound is playing correctly on a computer but not on a mobile device, your audio may have poor mono compatibility.

Videos often have stereo audio, which contains audio for left and right speakers (like headphones). Most mobile devices only have one speaker. When your mobile device plays stereo audio, it has to convert it to mono (single speaker) audio before your video plays.

If the audio in your video has poor “mono compatibility”, the mono conversion process can reduce the audio quality or mute the audio. This problem often happens when several audio recordings are used in one video.

Make sure your audio is "in phase."